# how do you modify the actual css of a class rather than add a style to each element of that class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a google chrome extension to modify the look of tumblr for a project. 
I'm trying to make the posts to go down in multiple colums rather than just one, It is going... alright. Except as some of you might know tumblr loads new posts as you scroll down. Those new posts aren't getting the css I am adding to the class with JQuery. Does anyone have a suggestion as how to modify the actual contents of the css of the class in general rather than apply a style to all the elements with that class as what seems to be happening with .ccs()?

Here is my code at the moment:

```
$("#posts.posts>.post_container").css({
    "display":"inline-flex",
    "margin":"100px",

});
```

But only the posts that have been loaded on the page get the style..

Thank you for any help I can get!

Comment: Try: `$("<style type='text/css'>#posts.posts>.post_container { display:inline-flex; margin:100px; }</style>").appendTo("head");
`

Comment: Thanks so much that works perfectly! Solves actually more than just that one problem!

Comment: Would anyone know how I could find the event that triggers when more posts are loaded as not everything I am modifying is css but also strings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$('<style>', { 
  type: 'text/css',
  text: '#posts.posts>.post_container { display:inline-flex; margin:100px; }'
}).appendTo('head');
```

This appends a new `style` tag to `<head>`. The style in that newly appended tag will be applied to everything in the document (well except iframes).

Comment: @phenomnomnominal nice edit. Didn't know that you could append `style` tags like that.

Comment: `$('<element>', { attribute: 'value' });` works for any kind of DOM element, it's super handy.